# How to fix Conflicting responsive menu Css and Colorbox css?

Tags: css, responsive-design, colorbox

I'm trying to integrate a responsive menu to my website [here](http://www.bravotech.me/skeleton/menu.html) but I also have a colorbox script running on it. The thing is, The css of the responsive menu ( which i got [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/code-a-responsive-navigation-menu/)) is messing up my colorbox css. the css is as follows:

colorbox css:

```
/*
    ColorBox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999;
 overflow:hidden; }
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box;}
```

the Responsive menu css is as follows:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto; 
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
   /* overflow: hidden; */
}

nav li a {
    background: #444;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: 400 13px/1.4 'Cutive', Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 12.5%;

        /*TRANSISTIONS*/
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
       -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease;
         -o-transition: background 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease;
            transition: background 0.5s ease;
}


 /*HOVER*/
nav li a:hover , nav li a.current{
    background: #222;
}

nav li a:visited {
    color:#FFF;
}

nav li:last-child a {
    border: none;
}

/*SMALL*/
nav small {
    color: #aaa;   
    font: 100 11px/1 Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;

}

...more responsive css STUFF ( unimportant)
```

**I've located the Issue.** I need help fixing it. when I open up the colorbox pictures, the box itself is smaller than the rest of the popup. so It looks aweful, I'm testing it in FireFox 18.0.1 but if I use Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56 m and it works in Chrome ( it shows teh whole thing)

The issue is with this line in the menu css:

```
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

and I'm not too familiar with it to know what its doing, but I know If I take it out, my resposive design menu doesn't work preperly, but my colorbox does. I'm thinking of taking it away from the "*" portion of the css and add it somewhere else, but how can I do this? can I hard code it to a div or something? here is my html:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/menu-css.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorboxjs/colorbox/colorbox1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorboxjs/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".gallery3").colorbox({rel:'gallery3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            });
        </script>


</head>
<body>



    <!-- Primary Page Layout
    ================================================== -->

    </div><!-- container -->


    <div class="container" style="background:lightgray; padding: 15px">
        <h3> 5 menu right </h3>
        <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
        </ul>       
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background:lightgray; padding: 15px">
    <P>THIRD TYPE - No Transition + fixed width and height (75% of screen size)</P>
        <a class='gallery3' href='images/slider-1.jpg'>Pic 1</a>
        <a class='gallery3' href='images/slider-2.jpg'>Pic 2</a>
        <a class='gallery3' href='images/slider-3.jpg'>Pic 3</a>
    </div>  
    <br/><br/>
<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
        <script>
            jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox();
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

THanks for all the help in advanced. ~Myy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What box-sizing: border-box; does is, it will include all border and padding widths/length in your content-width. so instead of 1px border + 50px width = 52px total width, border-box will always force the total-width to be 50px.

You can always use media-queries and start using the border-box from a certain screen-size, that would seperate your normal and mobile css pretty well, but it will cause similar errors on the small screen which you need to fix.
Here's a quick intro about media-queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Alternatively you can get rid of the border-box and manually nudge any changes you see back in place (use FF's firebug or Chrome developer tools for this). But I do want to add that border-box is pretty cool & handy, you should consider leaving it in and nudging your default code.

Comment: thanks for helping because I coudln't find anything online about box-sizing. so tell me how can I apply to it a certain div? can you show me an example of it being used anywhere else?

Comment: ok I got it, I had to remove the " overflow:hidden; " from the #colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper. and now it works, and I kept the box sizing for FF. what was overflow, hidden doing? do you think I may have issues in the future?

Comment: I recommend testing on a couple of browsers. You can also reset the border-box for the responsive div's. This you can do with 'box-sizing: content-box;' If I'm not mistaken. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped :)